# sending bulk email in laravel from select options

Tags: php, laravel, forms, phpmailer, implode

Am trying to send bulk email from my laravel project sing PHPMailer, I get the emails from the select option in blade:

```
<form action="{{url('send/bulk/email')}}" method="post">
   @csrf
   <select name="recipient[]"   multiple data-mdb-filter="true" >
      <option value="glemar0@amazon.co.uk" >glemar0@amazon.co.uk</option>
      <option value="xfacey2@dion.ne.jp" >xfacey2@dion.ne.jp</option>
      <option value="lsenten3@tripod.com" >lsenten3@tripod.com</option>
      <option value="gchamperlen4@zimbio.com">gchamperlen4@zimbio.com</option>
      <option value="dgracey5@simplemachines.org" >dgracey5@simplemachines.org</option>
      <option value="mwildman6@amazon.co.jp" >mwildman6@amazon.co.jp</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

In Controller

```
public function sendBulkEmail(Request $request){
    try {
        $recipients = explode(',', $request->recipient);
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
        //Server settings                                    
        $mail->setFrom('sender@example.com', 'Sender');
        
        foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
           $mail->addAddress($recipient);
     }

    $mail->addReplyTo('sender@example.com', 'Information');

    $mail->isHTML(true);                  
    $mail->Subject = 'Request';
    $mail->Body    = 'this test message';
   } 
}
```

My error

```
explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, array given
```

Comment: a select input will send the value of only one option, the selected one.

Comment: Where is the "bulk" email?

Comment: Note that this will result in a single email with multiple recipients who all can see each others' email addresses. This is usually not what you want to do (unless it is so in that case just ignore me). Instead in the loop create a new email object with a single recipient and sent it before making another one

Comment: @apokryfos please advise on how i can do that.

Answer (score 2):

The `recipient` parameter in request is an array itself. You don't need to explode it.

```
$recipients = $request->recipient ;
```